# How to format a html with css, js and explanatory note in sublime?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using HTML/CSS/JS prettify plugin.
It's always doing a good job in format codes.
But recently when I learning react and input all the html,script,css,jsx and explanatory note in a html file, it can't format correctly.
like this:

[image]

Besides, I tried some solutions but still can't solve this problem.
like changing the attribution in prettify settings in js section,"e4x": true,

Comment: Besides,sometimes when typing  explanatory note in javascript, it destroyed the format, so I need to temove the  explanatory note like '// toto' or '/*todo*/' for formatting code correctly.

Comment: You can use prettier. https://github.com/prettier/prettier

Comment: ok, I'm trying to use this.Thanks a lot, konekoya